# Making password bullets for Eduroam in Wicd

Tags: templates, wpa-supplicant

In order to connect to Eduroam wifi on wicd, I added the following Eduroam file to my /etc/wicd/encryption/templates folder:

```
name = Eduroam
author = hautod
version = 1
require identity *Username password *Password
----
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant 
network={
    ssid="eduroam"
    scan_ssid=$_SCAN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=PEAP
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    identity="*uni email*"
    password="*password*"
}
```

and this works fine, apart from disconnecting often. I am a complete beginner here so found this solution somewhere online.

My question is: how can I make the password in the wicd properties pop up represent as bullets? I have to input this a lot in different uni buildings, and so a lot of people have seen my password.

I am running ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Please let me know if you need any more information, thank you for your help. I tried to find a solution on here but could not work it out for this particular file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out for those who have the same issue:

under this line:

```
require identity *Username password *Password
```

add:

```
protected password *Password
```

Comment: Why does this help? I cannot find any documentation on that directive.